# Is it ok to use react state in render prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

I have two components `App` and `MyComponent`, where `MyComponent` is used in `App`.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { MyComponent } from "./myComponent";

export const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <MyComponent
        render={() => (
          <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => prev + 50)}>{state}</button>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

```
export const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const Content = props.render;

  return (
    <div>
      <Content/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

---

Is it ok to use `state` in the return value of the `render` prop? Is it considered anti-pattern?

Comment: If you want a rendered component to dynamically be passed to a component, a canonical way to do that is through child components which are accessible in props.  See something like https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/17/react-children-the-misunderstood-prop/

Comment: Thank you, I am aware, but in case of using 'slots', i prefer using render props.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it ok to use react state in render prop?

Yes, but... why? `children` prop was created to achieve exactly what you want here.

```
<MyComponent>
  <button onClick={() => setState((prev) => prev + 50)}>{state}.</button>
</MyComponent>

export const MyComponent = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: I prefer to use render props rather than children in the cases where there are 'multiple' children placed in different places within the component.

Comment: Also, using a render function, it is possible to inject props, not otherwise available.

Comment: @johann1301s 1) its not the best idea, instead of passing components into different places, just re-arrange your component. 2) You can inject props into normal components too.